# Do I need drivers to use a full-sized Apple keyboard with my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, driver

I have a 2009 MacBook Pro and just purchased a wired Apple Keyboard with numeric keypad. I really wanted dedicated navigation keys, and it is working great in Eclipse after a bit of configuration. I also wanted proper mappings for Word given how non-standard it feels, and this works well out of the box. I've set up the extra function keys to swap between Spaces - all working fine.

However, in other apps like FireFox, the home and end keys are not working.

Do I need special drivers for the keyboard? I've checked the support site and found nothing relating to my keyboard.

Comment: FYI, in most text processing apps Cmd-LeftArrow moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, aka Home, and Cmd-RightArrow moves the cursor to the end of the line, aka End. Doesn't solve your problem of wanting to use those keys, but at least you'll know.

Comment: The problem is you get used to using home and end.

Comment: I agree. I continue to mis-press them after using a Mac almost exclusively for the last 18 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac OS X home and end keys do not function the same way as they do on other systems.

> On Mac, the Home and End keys go to the top and bottom of a document, instead of to the beginning or end of a line.

Check out this [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/225873/mac-switchers-tip--remap-the-home-and-end-keys) article which shows how to remap the functionality of the home and end keys to make them perform like they do on other systems.

Comment: From [Apple's Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGUserInput/XHIGUserInput.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000361-TPXREF61): "Pressing the Home key is equivalent to moving the scrollers all the way to the top and to the left.... End is the opposite of Home: It scrolls to the end of a document."